# etree.ElementTree add tag attribute with special char

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I want generate Element with attribute xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation.

```
<Test name="Name" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="anyURI"></a>
```

My python code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
root = xml.Element('Tests', xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="anyURI")
```

When I try run python file. getting error

> File ".../xml-generator.py", line 4
>       root = xml.Element('Tests', xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="anyURI")
>                                      ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the attribute later via `Element.set`:

```
root = xml.Element("Tests")
root.set("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "anyURI")
```

Or you could pack the kwargs to `Element` into a dictionary first and directly unpack them again using the `**` operator:

```
root = xml.Element("Tests", **{"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" : "anyURI"})
```